# Why can we use $Tr(AB) = Tr(A)Tr(B)$ when finding matrix element squared?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, matrix-elements

Here is a $t$-channel Feynman diagram I'm working on:
[image]
Using Feynman's rules, we can find the matrix element as
$$
M_t = -ig^2\frac{\bar u^{s_3}(p_3)u^{s_2}(p_2)\bar u^{s_4}(p_4)u^{s_1}(p_1)}{(p_2-p_3)^2-m^2}
$$

Then, we have

$$
\sum_{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} |M_t|^2= \frac{g^4}{[(p_2-p_3)^2-m^2]^2}\text{Tr}[u^{s_3}(p_3)\bar u^{s_3}(p_3)u^{s_2}(p_2)\bar u^{s_2}(p_2)]\times\text{Tr}[ u^{s_4}(p_4)\bar u^{s_4}(p_4) u^{s_1}(p_1)\bar u^{s_1}(p_1)]
$$

I was actually told to split the trace into two parts like the step above, then we can use the identity $\sum_{s}u\bar u = \not p +m$ for further simplification. However, I don't quite understand why we can do that, because generally $\text{Tr}(AB)\neq\text{Tr}(A)\text{Tr}(B)$.

Thanks!

Comment: They didn't use that "identity," there are in fact two separate traces here, but you've left out the part of the calculation that would show you that step.

Comment: I have no idea about Feynman diagrams but a following equality is true: Tr(A•B)=Tr(A)Tr(B), where • is tensor product. Maybe your multiplication can be interpreted is this way?

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks for the comment! Then which identity I should use? Could you point me to some links for that? I think I got really stuck on this part.

Comment: It would probably help more if you illustrated your steps, I find that Griffiths particle physics book has a nice simple intro to how to do the steps in-between squaring and arriving at the traces.

Comment: @Triatticus I just checked out Casimir's trick and now it makes sense to me. Thank you!